# Is frational ideal finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be Noetherian.

I know finitely generated $R$-submodule $I$ of $K$ is a fractional ideal. It is easy to see.

But why if $R$-submodule $I$ of $K$ is a fractional ideal then it is finitely generated? hard to understand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $I$ is a fractional ideal, then there is some non-zero $r\in R$ with $rI\subset R$. But as $R$ is noetherian we have $rI=(f_1,\dots,f_n)$ for some $f_i\in R$, hence $I=(\frac{f_1}{r},\dots,\frac{f_n}{r})$ is finitely generated.

Comment: why $rI$ is finite? I is not usual ideal of R

Comment: @CometOh $rI$ is an ideal of $R$. $R$ being noetherian means that every ideal of $R$ is finitely generated. Therefore $rI$ is finitely generated. (By $(f_1,\dots,f_n)$ I mean the ideal generated by the $f_i$.)

Comment: Sorry to ask. why $rI$ is an ideal of $R$? I know $rI$ is just a subset of $R$.

Comment: @CometOh By definition $I$ is a $R$-submodule of $K$. If you multiply it with $r$, it will still be a $R$-submodule of $K$. But if $rI\subset R$ then it is furthermore a $R$-submodule of $R$, i.e. an ideal of $R$. Of course, you can also verify the ideal-properties directly